# Django 1.5 + TastyPie 0.10 Gives "cannot import name ModelResource"

Tags: python, django, apache, tastypie

After update Django & Tastypie I receive a "cannot import name ModelResource".  How can I fix this issue?

I am currently trying to update a Django install to Django 1.5, and also up to the latest version of Tastypie.  I've done this twice before (once on my dev MacBook Pro and again on a pre-release server, identical to the one I'm upgrading now).  Both times I remember having trouble, but both times I just got it working... I don't know how!

It has now happened a third time, and my frantic "uninstall then reinstall until it works" strategy has so far failed.  I'm running an Apache server, though so it my pre-production that is working (I have checked that all django & module versions match).

Has anyone run into this issue and is away of the magic sequence to fix this?

Full Trackback follow:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://10.32.232.50/

Django Version: 1.5.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django_extensions',
 'floppyforms',
 'crispy_forms',
 'tastypie',
 'userProfile',
 'modeling',
 'aliance',
 'launchpad',
 'visitorlog',
 'experience_controller')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "c:\AbacusCore\abacus\urls.py" in <module>
  3. from api import *
File "c:\AbacusCore\abacus\api.py" in <module>
  4. from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.7.egg\tastypie\resources.py" in <module>
  19. from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.7.egg\tastypie\authentication.py" in <module>
  14. from tastypie.compat import User, username_field
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_tastypie-0.10.0-py2.7.egg\tastypie\compat.py" in <module>
  14.         User = get_user_model()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in get_user_model
  127.     user_model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\loading.py" in get_model
  230.             self._populate()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\loading.py" in _populate
  75.                     self.load_app(app_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\db\models\loading.py" in load_app
  96.             models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "c:\AbacusCore\visitorlog\models.py" in <module>
  6. from tastypie.resources import ModelResource

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name ModelResource
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your installation of tastypie  in your PYTHONPATH?

---

If you open up a command prompt (make sure you're in the right virtual env if you use that) and run:

```
bash: echo $PYTHONPATH
```

or, from a python debugger open at the exception point:

```
>>>import os
>>>os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
```

then make sure that the directory you've installed tastypie into, is in one of the directories listed.

Comment: Yes.  I'm just upgrading from older versions, and everything actually works with Tastypie 0.9.12 (which I've reverted to for now).  It is truly perplexing to me.

Comment: How are you starting your application?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're looking for when referring to "starting" the application.  On the dev (working Django 1.5 + Tastypie 0.10) machine I use `./manage.py runserver`; on the working pre-production server and the problematic deployment server we use an Apache server which points.

Comment: I bet you have two installations of tastypie on the prod server, and are only upgrading one (or something like that). Have you made 100% sure that the install is in your path? Try adding "print os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)" to wsgi.py on your production server, and restarting apache?